# REST endpoint for getting a url for displaying an envelope's history in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I was going through the API references of DocuSign and Found "RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken" SOAP request which returns a url which displays history of that document. I am trying to find same or similar functionality using REST.

PS. I found the REST request for "[audit_events](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Audit%20Events.htm)" for any envelope, from which I have to construct the history from the response I receive. But I don't want that. I want DocuSign to display that information for me on some URL.

Comment: I suspect that the closest you'll find is the REST audit_events end point. But I'm checking further to ensure that my information is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too spoke to a memeber of DocuSign API , there is no REST API equivalent to SOAP API "RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken" .So if we want a url which displays us history of envelope signatures we have to use SOAP API only , or we can use REST API "audit_events" and store the events in our application.

Answer (score 0):

A member of the API developer team tells me that no REST equivalent to the  "[RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?op=RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken)" SOAP request exists.

I suggest that you consider calling the SOAP method.

Remember that you can call the SOAP endpoint directly. You don't need to use your stack's SOAP plumbing/libraries/etc unless you wish to.